# Spring Integration: Manual channel handling

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-messaging

What I want: Build a configurable library that

- uses another library that has an internal routing and a subscribe method like: `clientInstance.subscribe(endpoint, (endpoint, message) -> <handler>)` , e.g. Paho MQTT library
- later in my code I want to access the messages in a `Flux`.

My idea:

- create MessageChannels like so:

  ```
  integrationFlowContext
      .registration(IntegrationFlows.from("message-channel:" + endpoint)).bridge().get())
      .register()
  ```
- forward to reactive publishers:

  ```
  applicationContext.registerBean(
       "publisher:" + endpoint,
       Publisher.class,
       () -> IntegrationFlows.from("message-channel:" +     endpoint)).toReactivePublisher()
      );
  ```
- keep the message channels in a set or similar and implement the above handler: `(endpoint, message) -> messageChannels.get(endpoint).send( <converter>(message))`
- later use (in a `@PostConstruct` method):

  ```
  Flux
     .from((Publihser<Message<?>>)applicationContext.getBean("publisher:" + enpoint))
     .map(...)
     .subscribe()
  ```

I doubt this to be the best way to do what I want. Feels like abusing spring integration. Any suggestions are welcome at this point.

In general however (at least in my tests) this seemed to be working. But when I run my application, I get errors like: "Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available".

This is especially bad, since after this exception the publishers claim to not have a subscriber anymore. Thus, in a real application no messages are proceeded anymore.

I am not sure what this message means, but I can kind of reproduce it (but don't understand why):

```
@Test
public void channelTest() {
    integrationFlowContext
            .registration(
                    IntegrationFlows.from("any-channel").bridge().get()
            )
            .register();

    registryUtil.registerBean(
            "any-publisher",
            Publisher.class,
            () -> IntegrationFlows.from("any-channel").toReactivePublisher()
    );

    Flux
            .from((Publisher<Message<?>>) applicationContext.getBean("any-publisher"))
            .subscribe(System.out::println);

    MessageChannel messageChannel = applicationContext.getBean("any-channel", MessageChannel.class);
    try {
        messageChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("test").build());
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        log.error("Error: ", t);
    }

}
```

I of course read parts of the spring integration documentation, but don't quite get what happens behind the scenes. Thus, I feel like guessing possible error causes.

**EDIT:**

This, however works:

```
@TestConfiguration
static class Config {

    GenericApplicationContext applicationContext;
    Config(
            GenericApplicationContext applicationContext,
            IntegrationFlowContext integrationFlowContext
    ) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        // optional here, but needed for some reason in my library,
        // since I can't find the channel beans like I will do here,
        // if I didn't register them like so:
        //integrationFlowContext
        //    .registration(
        //    IntegrationFlows.from("any-channel").bridge().get())
        //    .register();

        applicationContext.registerBean(
                "any-publisher",
                Publisher.class,
                () -> IntegrationFlows.from("any-channel").toReactivePublisher()
        );

    }

    @PostConstruct
    void connect(){
        Flux
                .from((Publisher<Message<?>>) applicationContext.getBean("any-publisher"))
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
    }

}

@Autowired
ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Autowired
IntegrationFlowContext integrationFlowContext;

@Test
@SneakyThrows
public void channel2Test() {

    MessageChannel messageChannel = applicationContext.getBean("any-channel", MessageChannel.class);
    try {
        messageChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("test").build());
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        log.error("Error: ", t);
    }

}
```

Thus apparently my issue above is realted to messages arriving "too early" .. I guess?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your issue is related to *round-robin* dispatched on the `DirectChannel` for the `any-channel` bean name.

You define two `IntegrationFlow` instances starting with that channel and then you declare their own subscribers, but at runtime both of them are subscribed to the same `any-channel` instance. And that one comes with the *round-robin* balancer by default. So, one message goes to your `Flux.from()` subscriber, but another to that `bridge()` which doesn't know what to do with your message, so it tries to resolve a `replyChannel` header.

Therefore your solution just only with one `IntegrationFlows.from("any-channel").toReactivePublisher()` is correct. Although you could just do a `FluxMessageChannel` registration and use it from one side for regular messages sending and from other side as a reactive source for `Flux.from()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification, makes a lot of sense now. However, it sounds like `FluxMessageChannel` is exactly what I need. Maybe you could give me a hint, how to register it correctly (programmatically).

Comment: The `ApplicationContext.registerBean()` is OK to use here. The `FluxMessageChannel` comes with default simple constructor.

Comment: Thank, you I'll try all that and in case open a new question. `FluxMessageChannel` so far seems to solve all the issues I've had.